# How to do format code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to start writing some Selenium scripts using Visual Studio Code.

What is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on Windows in Visual Studio for formatting or "beautifying" code in the Visual Studio Code editor?

Answer (score 0):

Windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
Mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>